# Misplacement of x in a bar chart with legend

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I recently started using `LaTeX` for my bachelor thesis and I am unable to resolve the misplacement of the symbolic x coordinates. Also, I would like to have a consistent spacing between the different bars.

I suspect that I somehow used the `\addplot´ coordinates wrong, but maybe there is a simple fix for my problem?

[image]

This is the code for the figure:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
                title={Top ten ranking distributions for page hits in 2021 on distrowatch.com},
                ybar,
                ylabel={Hits per day},
                ymin=0,
                ymax=4000,
                width=\textwidth,
                xtick=data,%{MX Linux,EndevaourOS,Manjaro,Mint,Pop! OS,Ubuntu,Debian,elementary,Garuda,Fedora},
                x tick label style={rotate=90, align=center},
                symbolic x coords={MX Linux,EndevaourOS,Manjaro,Mint,Pop! OS,Ubuntu,Debian,elementary,Garuda,Fedora},
                % point meta=explicit symbolic,
                nodes near coords,
                % legend columns=3,
                % enlarge x limits=true,
                %unbounded coords=jump,
            ]
            \addplot coordinates {
                    (MX Linux, 3384)
                    (Mint, 2067)
                    (Pop! OS, 1668)
                    (Ubuntu, 1339)
                    (Debian, 1274)
                    (elementary, 1101)
                };

            \addplot coordinates {
                    (EndevaourOS, 2601)
                    (Manjaro, 2302)
                    (Garuda, 1081)
                };

            \addplot coordinates {
                    (Fedora, 997)
                };
            \legend{APT, Pacman, DNF}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE (Minimal Working Example) so that we can reproduce your figure.

Comment: The thing is that when using multiple addplots with a barplot, pgfplots makes a plot with a *group* of bars centered around each x-tick. Each addplot adds a new member to these groups. You have three addplots, so pgfplots makes room for three bars at each x-coordinate. I think there are a couple of questions on the site about changing the colors of individual bars, so try searching if you haven't already.

Comment: Ah sorry, I created a MWE now. Thank you I will try to search for that and update here if I find something.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a way to shift the bar groups so that it looks fine.
While I don't really find this solution elegant in any way, it works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
                title={Top ten ranking distributions for page hits in 2021 on distrowatch.com},
                ybar,
                ylabel={Hits per day},
                ymin=0,
                ymax=4000,
                width=\textwidth,
                % xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
                % xticklabels={MX Linux,EndevaourOS,Manjaro,Mint,Pop! OS,Ubuntu,Debian,elementary,Garuda,Fedora}
                %xtick=data,%{MX Linux,EndevaourOS,Manjaro,Mint,Pop! OS,Ubuntu,Debian,elementary,Garuda,Fedora},
                x tick label style={rotate=90, align=center},
                symbolic x coords={MX Linux,EndevaourOS,Manjaro,Mint,Pop! OS,Ubuntu,Debian,elementary,Garuda,Fedora},
                % point meta=explicit symbolic,
                nodes near coords,
                % legend columns=3,
                % enlarge x limits=true,
                %unbounded coords=jump,
                %table/x expr=\coordindex,
            ]

            \addplot [red, fill=red!30!white, bar shift=0.5pt] coordinates {
                    (MX Linux, 3384)
                    (Mint, 2067)
                    (Pop! OS, 1668)
                    (Ubuntu, 1339)
                    (Debian, 1274)
                    (elementary, 1101)
                };

            \addplot [green, fill=green!20!white] coordinates {
                    (EndevaourOS, 2601)
                    (Manjaro, 2302)
                    (Garuda, 1081)
                };

            \addplot [blue, fill=blue!30!white, bar shift=-0.5pt] coordinates  {
                    (Fedora, 997)
                };

            \legend{APT, Pacman, DNF}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you could add an image of the current result. Then it would be easier for others to see, if this is also a suitable solution for them. Could you edit your answer accordingly?

Comment: Why `bar shift=0.5pt` (and `bar shift=-0.5pt`) - any reason, you do not want it exactly cantered(`bar shift=0`) ?